# CrudRepository save method returned entity has no proxy for child entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

When a user adds a new record in frontend, this backend method is called:

```
@PostMapping(path = "recordings/add")
@Transactional
public RecordingDTO add(@RequestBody RecordingDTO recordingDTO) {
    Recording recording = new Recording();
    recording.setAgentId(recordingDTO.getAgent().getId());
    recording.setProjectId(recordingDTO.getProject().getId());
    ... other irrelevant fields are set here...

    Recording savedRecording = recordingsRepository.save(recording);
    Recording retrievedSavedRecording = recordingsRepository.findById(savedRecording.getId()).get();
    return new RecordingDTO(retrievedSavedRecording);
}
```

*Recording* is an entity that looks like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "agent_id")
private Long agentId;

@Column(name = "project_id")
private Long projectId;

... more columns here; omitted for not being relevant

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "agent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Agent agent;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Project project;
```

So the *Recording* entity has 2 child entities associated with it: Agent and Project. The problem is that after save is called the *savedEntity* doesn't have the getAgent() and getProject() methods proxied. The agent and project fields are null. Even the *retrievedSavedRecording* doesn't have those 2 fields.

What do I have to do in order to be able to retrive the agent and the project child entities?

Comment: You are using the same column twice  first as id then as entity, remove agentId and projectId then it should work

Comment: I need to use it like that because when I'm choosing an agent from a dropdown with agents (or a project from a dropdown with projects), the backend should create a new row in Recordings table with the agent_id that was chose from that dropdown.

Comment: Use `@MapsId` instead of `@JoinColumn` then you can use Recording id for both. The way you are trying may not possible. See here for suggested approach https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: If I use `@MapsId` I get this error: `Recording column: project_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`. If I map it like that then when I will try to add a new Recording to the database the project_id and agent_id will not be stored. What I want is that when I create a Recording entity to be able to set agent_id and project_id and when I'm reading a Recording entity to be able to receive Agent and Project as entities on Recording entity.

Answer (score 0):

- Try this first, it might work as it works for database generated columns but here pretending that relation is database generated.

```
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id", ....)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    public Agent agent;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"...)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    public Project project;
```

- If that does not work, you can try by creating a service and it will probably work and remove the `@Transactional` from controller.

```
    @PostMapping(path = "recordings/add")
    public RecordingDTO add(@RequestBody RecordingDTO recordingDTO) {
       Recording recording = new Recording();
       recording.setAgentId(recordingDTO.getAgent().getId());
       recording.setProjectId(recordingDTO.getProject().getId());
       ... other irrelevant fields are set here...
       
       Recording savedRecording = recordingService.save(recording);


       return new RecordingDTO(retrievedSavedRecording);
    }
```

```
     @Service
     public class RecordingService {

        @Autowired
        RecordingsRepository recordingsRepository;

        @Transactional
        public Recording findById(Long id){
          Recording retrievedSavedRecording 
                 =  recordingsRepository.findById(recording);
          return new RecordingDTO(retrievedSavedRecording); 
        }
        
        @Transactional
        public RecordingDTO saveRecording(Recording recording){
          return recordingsRepository.save(recording);
        }
        

     }
```